# Linking external static library with project via cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a problem with this repo: https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip . I built it as it was written in **Build** . However, I didn't understood, what should be as a result? Static library or any package?
On picture you can see all files that were generated by 2 cmds.
[image]

As a result I don't know, how to connect it to my project. Here is my CMakeLists.txt.

```CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(MZ2
        LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-std=c++14 -pthread")

include_directories(/home/julian/Desktop/minizip-ng-master)

find_package(minizip 3.0.2 EXACT REQUIRED PATHS /home/julian/Desktop/minizip-ng-master)

add_executable(MZ2 main.cpp)

target_compile_definitions(MZ2 PRIVATE -DHAVE_STDINT_H;-DHAVE_INTTYPES_H;-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DHAVE_ZLIB;-DHAVE_LZMA;-DLZMA_API_STATIC;-DHAVE_ICONV;-DMZ_ZIP_SIGNING;-DHAVE_PKCRYPT;-DHAVE_WZAES)
 target_compile_definitions(MZ2 PRIVATE -DHAVE_COMPAT)

target_include_directories(MZ2 PRIVATE /home/julian/Desktop/minizip-ng-master)
target_link_libraries(MZ2  minizip)
```

As a result I have an error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable MZ2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lminizip
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/MZ2.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'MZ2' failed
make[3]: *** [MZ2] Error 1
```

I understood that compiler can't find nessecary "minizip" library.
So, what can I do in this situation?

Comment: It does not look like the folder you are showing contains the compiled output.

Comment: You need to paste the full message output from `cmake`, it will be very useful to investigate the problem.

Comment: Not sure why `find_package(minizip)` is succeed for you: the directory you show misses even **build** artifacts, but `find_package` requires the package to be **installed**. But as this call succeed, it should create imported target `MINIZIP::minizip`. So you could use this target instead of `minizip` in `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: The screenshot you've posted does not look like the install directory,but like the source directory of a in source (duh) build.Specify a directory to install the library to at the time you configure the minizip project,install the project and pass the path you installed the project to to`find_package`instead of  the build directory:`mkdir minizip-build` `mkdir minizip-install` `cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=minizip-install ... -S minizip-ng-master -B minizip-build` `cmake --build minizip-build` `cmake --install minizip-build` `find_package(minizip...PATHS /home/julian/Desktop/minizip-install)`